# Python executing Class-dump command

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute the following code in Python

```
import os,subprocess
from glob import glob

path = "/Users/armed/private_SDKs"
os.chdir(path)

for file in glob("*.framework"):
     command = ['class-dump' , '-H' , file , '-o' , '~', '/Users/armed/Desktop/Headers/']
     subprocess.call(command)
```

On executing this script i get the following error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.call(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: Looks like you have a     "Permission denied" -  Try to chmod the subprocess ?

Comment: Do permissions get denied in python ? Because the command runs perfectly when called from the mac terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions of the class-dump command.  `chmod +x class-dump` if it's not executable.  Here are the docs on [chmod](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html).

You might also need to specify the absolute path to class-dump if it's not on your path.

Also, try:

```
print " ".join(command)
```

and see if you can run it by pasting the results into a shell.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback ! I definitely was not using the full path that solved some parts of my error. But it still seems to say permission denied even after i added in this line - subprocess.call('chmod -x /Developer/usr/bin/class-dump'). Any other way in which i can use chmod ?

Comment: You don't want to do the chmod from the python script. That's a one time command that tells the os that it's an executable file rather than a data file.  Once you run it, the file should be executable.  However, -x and +x have the opposite effect. If you ran the -x command, you need to change it back to +x before you can run it.

Comment: As I already said, the command works perfectly well when given from the terminal. When i give the command through python, the above error comes up.